# Copy the graph and other controls to clipboard

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, clipboard

I have a windows forms c# .Net 4 application that generates a chart using the MS Chart control, I also have a standard label in the lower righthand corner. i have added a right click copy function to the graph but needless to say it doesn't copy the Label control as well.

I there a way of putting a label as part of the Chart control at this location 
or
how do i copy both to the clipboard so they are able to be pasted in to Word or another application?

```
private void menuCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
            if (menuItem != null)
            {
                // Retrieve the ContextMenu that contains this MenuItem
                ContextMenu menu = menuItem.GetContextMenu();

                // Get the control that is displaying this context menu
                Control sourceControl = menu.SourceControl;

                if (sourceControl is Chart)
                {
                    Chart chartToCopy = (Chart)sourceControl;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        chartToCopy.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Bmp);
                        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
                        Clipboard.SetImage(bm);
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

And this is what I'm trying to copy to the clipboard:
[image]

Edit 1:
I have updated the code to copy the contents of the hosting Tab control but it still only copies the graph!

```
 using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tabControl1.TabPages[3].Width, tabControl1.TabPages[3].Height))
                    {
                        tabControl1.TabPages[3].DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0),
                        tabControl1.TabPages[3].Size));
                        Clipboard.SetImage(bmp);
                    }
```

Comment: You can use [`DrawToBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) method of form.

Comment: 'of Form' or of common container, or if you __nest__ the Labels in the Chart of the Chart.

Comment: thanks for the replies I have updated my code to try DrawToBitmap but it does not include the label, it just copies the chart again! 
the Chart is docked in the Tab does that impact things?

 #confused!

Comment: @Adrian When you call `DrawToBitmap` of a control, the whole content of control will be drawn to bitmap. For example if your `tabControl1.TabPages[3]` doesn't contain the label, you can not expect the label be painted to output bitmap. You can set the `Label` to be docked to bottom of your tab and set your chart to be docked to fill your tab, then draw your tab page to bitmap.

Comment: Hi Reza, the Label is contained within the tab and is visible on screen when I call DrawToBitMap. does it really need to be docked to be captured?
I have just tried it with it docked and it still doesn't capture it :(

Comment: You need to __nest__ the Label: `yourLabel.Parent = yourChart`. Note that you also must now correct the position to being relativ to the new parent..

Comment: Thanks TaW, I can't mark this as the solution as it's a comment, but you seem to be the man for all things Chart related. it fixed the issue. Thank you.